# How we can put a corner ribbon on a dropdown section?

Tags: php, html, css

On my website exercise I need to put a corner ribbon on a dropdown section.
I have a button, with a dropdown section inside, and I want to put a ribbon for a promotion. 
But my ribbon still bellow my `div` and not on my bottom right hand corner
My HTML code is the following :

```
<div>
     <a class="dropdown-item" href="<?php echo $href_brown ?>">
      <?php 
      if (($current_language !== "/de") && ($promotion)){
       echo "<div class=\"corner-ribbon-buy-button\"><span>$20 off</span></div>";
          }
         ?>
          first product 

         <br>
         <?php 
       if (($current_language !== "/de") && ($promotion)){
         echo "<span style=\"font-style: italic;\"> Starting at 
         <span style=\"text-decoration:line-through;\">$149</span> $129 </span>";
            }
          ?>
         </a>
```

And my CSS is code is :

```
 .corner-ribbon-buy-button {
      -webkit-transition: 200s linear;
      transition: 200ms linear;
      position: relative;
      // left: 0px;
      top: 0;
      z-index: 1;
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 91px;
      height: 91px;
      text-align: right;
      line-height: 50px;

    }
    .corner-ribbon-buy-button span {
      font-size: 12px;
      color: #fff;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 30px;
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
      display: block;
      background: #0070c9;
      position: relative;
      top: 25px;
      z-index: 1;

    }
```

How can I put my ribbon at the bottom right hand corner of my dropdown div please ?

Comment: `position: absolute;bottom:0;right:0;` - but that comes with it's own set of problems, the parent element should be `position:relative` and the ribbon should have a set height.  `position: absolute` takes an element and removes it from the Box Model or the Document Flow if you will.

Comment: Post the rendered HTML, not the PHP.

Comment: thank you @ArtisticPhoenix your answer was very useful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple example

```css
#main {
  position:relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #999;
}

.ribbon{
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    background-color: red;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="main" >
  <div class="ribbon"></div>
</div>
```